# Reduce logo size for sticky header based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, html

This question has been asked here many times but I am looking to do this differently using Vanilla Javascript and not jQuery.

I need to reduce the logo size based on the scroll position but not suddenly. Adding a class to reduce the logo size is understood but I am looking to have the logo grow/shrink based on the exact scroll position.

The logo needs to stop at 200px wide down from 300px wide on scroll down.

When the user scrolls back up to a certain point the logo begins to increase back to 300px but still based on scroll position and not instantly based on a point.

Something similar to this on Codepen:
https://codepen.io/jonathanphz/pen/NAXRKG

````
var expandDiv = document.getElementById("expand");
var speed = 5;

function expanding() {
  var scrolltop = window.pageYOffset; // get number of pixels document has scrolled vertically
  var scrollAndSpeed = (scrolltop / speed);
  //Expand using transform
  //expandDiv.style.transform = "scalex( " + Math.min(Math.max(scrollAndSpeed, 1), 10) + ")";
  
  //Or using width
  expandDiv.style.width = Math.min(Math.max(scrollAndSpeed, 20), 95) + "%";

}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { // on page scroll
  requestAnimationFrame(expanding); // call parallaxing()
}, false);```
````

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet! Still looking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.onscroll` in vanilla JavaScript.

add condition with `document.body.scrollTop` and compare it, then change the styling(width and  height) accordingly.

It will help you.